# How to list out all the user created daemon processes

Tags: services, process

Is there any command which list out all the Daemon processes created by users to perform some tasks. I have created various daemon processes and I want to kill it manually by checking its pid how can I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All running processes (daemon and otherwise) can be listed using `ps aux`, you can filter out the process using `grep` on its output as follows:

```
ps aux | grep <process_name>
```

this would list its PID as well, which you can use to kill the process using:

```
kill <pid>
```

For, example, when I execute:

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```

on my system, I get:

```
mysql     3933  0.0  1.2 418616 46832 ?        Ssl  10:21   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

where `3933` is the pid, which I can kill using:

```
kill 3933
```

(I required `sudo` here, since I am not the owner of the process)

Or if you know the exact process name and it has only one running instance or you want to kill all running instances, you could use:

```
killall <process_name>
```

You could also use

```
pidof <process_name>
```

to get just the pid of the concerned process, however, you need to know the exact process name.

Comment: Yes but can i list out all the Daemon process created by user and created by server like the system generated daemon will have the ppid=1 but how to know the daemon which user has created.

Comment: @ali786: I didn't get you, `ps aux` will list all processes by all users, if you just want the processes for a single user `user`, just do `ps -U <username>`.